# Maven not using default repository following Spring.io Maven tutorial

Tags: java, maven

I'm following the Spring Maven tutorial found [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/).  I've followed it word-for-word twice to make sure I didn't make any mistakes, but I must have made one (the same one, twice) anyway.  The last step of the tutorial fails, i.e. adding an external dependency, the Joda Time library.  I've confirmed the dependencies exist in my `~/.m2/repository` directory.  I've confirmed my program compiles up until I reach this last step of the tutorial.  Now, I get the error that the variable LocalTime (symbol) cannot be found.

HelloWorld.java:

```
package hello;

import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
        System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        System.out.println(greeter.sayHello());
    }
}
```

Greeter.java:

```
package hello;

public class Greeter {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Remaining sanity:

```
null
```

Note, my Maven config file `settings.xml` is default for the installation.  For what it's worth, Maven is version 3.3.9.

Comment: Enable maven debugging, so that you can find what is going on. mvn compile -X (-X to enable debugging) , I am assuming you are not using any IDE.

Comment: How frustrating.  I followed your suggestion, and the project just compiled with no errors.  The only thing I did differently was restarting my computer.  No edits made to the `pom.xml` file.  How frustrating.

Comment: You will learn at the end of every frustration, enjoy the ride :-)